# Breakpoint won't hit in VSCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code, .net-core, vscode-debugger

I am new to VSCode and working on a sample project with VSCode, .Net Core and Angular CLI.
Created a basic User class and Registration class with SqlLite and EntityFramework in backend.
When i run the application, i am not able to hit any break points when attaching the .Net Core Attach process or from the Web Launch.
When tried to post data from postman the response is : the application completed without reading the entire request body
My working directory is C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Dateapp\DateApp.API>
Following is launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
// Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
// For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
"type": "coreclr",
"request": "launch",
"preLaunchTask": "build",
// If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/DateApp.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/DateApp.API.dll",
"args": [],
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DateApp.API",

        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",

        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "xdg-open"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",


    }
,]
}
```

And my CSProj file looks like below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: read this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: Thanks but  i believe the issue is with not understanding the environment of VSCode and how it works, as i am new and the above doc is for general purpose, did not provide much help.

Comment: Some very helpful tips to fix such problems:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7078b8/breakpoints-are-not-working-in-visual-studio/